# Get most trivial solutions to an equation from Solve[]

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a way to have Solve[] to return the most trivial solutions?
As an example if I consider the expression

```
a x + (b - B) (x+y)=0
```

I would like to find the simplest parameters $(a,b)$ which make the above true. In Mathematica calling

```
expr=a x + (b - B) (x+y);
Solve[expr==0,{a,b}]
```

would return {{b -> B - (a x)/(x + y)}}. Is there a way to have returned instead $a=0$, $b=B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways) is what you want here:

```
SolveAlways[a x + (b - B)(x+y) == 0, {x, y}]
```

> {{b -> B, a -> 0}}